# On two formulas involving the $k$-fold divisor function $d_k$ and the function $r_k$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-functions

I have a puzzle which needs some help form the experts here. Let $d(n)$ be the divisor function, and $d_k(n)$ the $k$-fold divisor function.

I)  It is known that, for any positive integer $h$,
$$d(n+h)d(n-h)=\sum_{ab=n+h}d(2n-ab)$$(see, e.g., Page 6 of Blomer's paper https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/am-pdf/10.1112/blms.12004).

My question is, for any positive integers $\ell, k$, whether or not we have the analogous formula involving $d_{\ell} $ and $d_k$？That is to see, if one has the formula of the type $$d_{\ell}(n+h)d_{k}(n-h)=\sum\cdots ?$$

II) More generaly, it is also known that, for $r_2(n)$ given by
$$r_k(n)=\sharp \{ (n_1,n_2.\ldots, n_k)\in \mathbb{Z}^k :n_1^2+n_2^2\cdots +n_k^2 =n\},\quad k \in \mathbb{N},$$
there exists the formula that
$$  r_2(n+h)r_2(n-h)=\sum _{ab=n+h} \chi(a) r_2(2n-ab),
$$where $\chi$ is the unique non-principal character modulo 4. My second question is whether or not we have the analogous formula involving $r_{\ell} $ and $r_k$ of the type $$r_{\ell}(n+h)r_{k}(n-h)=\sum\cdots ?$$

I searched these type of formulas in I) and II) in the references, but it seem there are no such records. If any expert knows something, please show me some hints or references.
Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: The identity $d(n + h) d(n - h) = \sum_{ab = n + h} d(2n - ab)$ just follows since $d(2n - ab) = d(n - h)$ as $ab = n + h$, while $\sum_{ab = n + h} 1 = d(n + h)$. So more generally $d_{\ell}(n + h) d_k(n - h) = \sum_{a_1 \cdots a_{\ell} = n + h} d_k(2n - a_1 \cdots a_{\ell})$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Great thanks for comments.